# AWS ec2 describe-instances IAM role does not work. UnauthorizedOperation when calling the DescribeInstances operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I wrote a Python script that gets all the ec2 instances from all the regions. The script works locally on my computer. Then, I deployed it as a lambda via serverless.

**But when I test the lambda on the console I get this error:**

```
ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 17, in get_ec2_instances
    for each_ins_in_reg in ec2_re.instances.all():
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 81, in __iter__
    for page in self.pages():
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 171, in pages
    for page in pages:
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/paginate.py", line 269, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/paginate.py", line 357, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
```

**How do I solve this error?**

**What IAM policies / permissions do I need to have for this role?**

In the IAM I have given myself permissions to "ec2DescribeRegionpolicy" for this role, but I still get this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error message says that you don't have permission to invoke `DescribeInstances`. Why do you think that adding permission for `ec2DescribeRegionpolicy` (which is incorrectly capitalized) will solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the lambda is not authorized to perform the action ec2:DescribeInstances. Ensure that the IAM role attached to the lambda has that action added to its policy in order for lambda to properly run.